# In-app billing: SampleApplication and store data in the database

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play

Can somebody please explain me why Android's [sample application](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_integrate.html#billing-download) stores data in the database only in `onRestoreTransactionsResponse` and not in `onRequestPurchaseResponse`?

Since it is done so I am not sure how to test my application - if I use [standard product ID](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/billing/billing_testing.html) (android.test.purchased), then `onRestoreTransactionsResponse` is never called.
If I use my own product id - I am getting error that purchases are not allowed (my app is uploaded to Android Market, but not published; product id is published).

(My application will support one product only - 'paid version of application', probably I should use some different from the sample application approach?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The explanation is available at *PurchaseObserver* file coming with Sample Application - 
**onRequestPurchaseResponse**:

```
/**
 * This is called when we receive a response code from Market for a
 * RequestPurchase request that we made.  This is NOT used for any
 * purchase state changes.  All purchase state changes are received in
 * {@link #onPurchaseStateChange(PurchaseState, String, int, long)}.
 * This is used for reporting various errors, or if the user backed out
 * and didn't purchase the item.  The possible response codes are:
 *   RESULT_OK means that the order was sent successfully to the server.
 *       The onPurchaseStateChange() will be invoked later (with a
 *       purchase state of PURCHASED or CANCELED) when the order is
 *       charged or canceled.  This response code can also happen if an
 *       order for a Market-managed item was already sent to the server.
 *   RESULT_USER_CANCELED means that the user didn't buy the item.
 *   RESULT_SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE means that we couldn't connect to the
 *       Android Market server (for example if the data connection is down).
 *   RESULT_BILLING_UNAVAILABLE means that in-app billing is not
 *       supported yet.
 *   RESULT_ITEM_UNAVAILABLE means that the item this app offered for
 *       sale does not exist (or is not published) in the server-side
 *       catalog.
 *   RESULT_ERROR is used for any other errors (such as a server error).
```

**onRestoreTransactionsResponse** is just about response to our request (not purchase status):

```
/**
 * This is called when we receive a response code from Android Market for a
 * RestoreTransactions request that we made.  A response code of
 * RESULT_OK means that the request was successfully sent to the server.
 */
```

If I call **onRestoreTransactionsResponse**, then **onRequestPurchaseResponse** is also called.

Answer (score 0):

One thing to know, to be able to test your own items you have to create a signed apk of you app and install it manually on your device (it was working for me that way, otherwise I had the same error you had)

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. But can I debug such application?